# RabbitMQ Erlang: erlang_cookie_sources Effective user: (none)

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, rabbitmqctl

On Windows my RabbitMQ works via the `localhost:15672` but I can't reach it otherwise. I have the same content in both `.erlang.cookie`. I think I have an unexpected return of this command `.\rabbitmq-diagnostics.bat erlang_cookie_sources` :

[image]
(none) should be **rabbitmq** and the file path has **\** and **/** ? And my RabbitMQ isn't reacheable. Any ideas to change the `Effective user`, the `file path` and what to check for my RabbitMQ ? `.\rabbitmqctl.bat status` is obviously on error.

---

NB: I installed with both methods Windows installer and Chocolatey and it doesn't change anything, the same error.